# 404 View not found [name, type, prefix]

Tags: component, development, joomla-4.x, front-end

I'm currently building a new Joomla! 4 component from scratch by following along [a series of blog posts](https://blog.astrid-guenther.de/en/der-weg-zu-joomla4-erweiterungen/) since I am new to Joomla! and its development.

I am using Joomla! 4.1.5

Unfortunately I am not able to get the front-end part working while the back-end part works fine. I always get the "View not found" error when trying to visit any front-end site of the component.

The error shown is this:

```
404 View not found [name, type, prefix]: foo, html, foo\component\bar\site\controller\displayView
```

What I did is:

1. Add a DisplayController to the site part with path `com_foo/src/Controller/DisplayController.php`

```
namespace Foo\Component\Bar\Site\Controller;

use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController;

class DisplayController extends BaseController
{
    public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = []): DisplayController
    {
        return parent::display($cachable, $urlparams);
    }
}
```

2. Add a View to the site part with path `com_foo/src/View/Foo/HtmlView.php`

```
namespace Foo\Component\Bar\Site\View\Foo;

use Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\HtmlView as BaseHtmlView;

class HtmlView extends BaseHtmlView
{
    public function display($template = null)
    {
        parent::display($template);
    }
}
```

3. Add a template with very basic content to the site part with path: `com_foo/tmpl/foo/default.php`

```
default template for foo part
```

4. Install component (with uninstalling the old one before).
5. Go to URL `http://localhost/index.php?option=com_foo&view=foo`
6. The error is shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. The `DisplayController` of the front-end part was lacking a proper constructor, once I added it the site part works as well.

```
namespace Foo\Component\Bar\Site\Controller;

use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController;

class DisplayController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct($config = [], MVCFactoryInterface $factory = null, ?CMSApplication $app = null, ?Input $input = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($config, $factory, $app, $input);
    }

    public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = []): DisplayController
    {
        return parent::display($cachable, $urlparams);
    }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. When constructor is not present in child class, parent constructor is called. Which is what your constructor is doing.

Comment: @Sharky Due to having some custom logic in my constructor, my exact error was not having the constructor overloaded properly.

Comment: You should have added this vital information to your question.